# Razor page change image within form by setting a checkbox

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

On a razor form submit page I would like to change a picture when a checkbox is set, before the form is posted though not trough JavaScript, but by pure razor code handled client side.

Not knowing the terms for it im unable to create sample code for this question, I believe though this should be possible with razor.

Comment: `change a picture when a checkbox is set, before the form is posted though not trough JavaScript, but by pure razor code handled client side.`I think you need to sue js to do it.

Comment: Why do you want this? What's the problem you are trying to solve? This is possible with Blazor, but with Razor view/page no. The Razor view/page is compiled to html as a response to a request and cannot be changed afterwards by the sender. Only JS can do that. Maybe you can build something with SignalR, but then you're recreating Blazor.

Comment: Well mainly for my understanding of blazor how things work and to see things can be done without javascript but in C# which was kinda the promish  be able to work without of Javascript. And I know JS can do it, but that's not what i'm trying to learn from it. And i know the model-controller, in this case, its client-side running post form,  and there it should change with the option.
Like setting delete should show a deleted image icon on that form, things like that.